# Using Boost.coroutine2 on ARM bare-metal

Tags: c++, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal, boost-context

I'm working on some embedded project, and I'd like to use coroutine in ARM cortex-M. Unfortunately, Boost.coroutine2 (which uses Boost.context inside) does not officially support it. Is there any way that I can tweak Boost library to be able to use Boost.context to work in ARM cortex-M?

Comment: I'm sure the answer is "yes". Have you looked at the source to see what the dependencies are?

Comment: @Steve It seems to be tweaking with some asm code (saving register states and so on) that I don't understand. If there are some resources that helps me implement asm code for ARM cortex-M, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This sounds like quite a heavyweight solution to run on a cortex m. Have you looked at other methods to achieve what you need. Things such as FreeRTOS will allow you to write 'threaded' applications, or writing your own task switcher on a cortex m is fairly trivial.